# What's the logic behind the expression "no hace falta"?

Tags: gramática, etimología, vocabulario, expresiones, historia

How come does `no hace falta` mean "there's no need/necessity" and the like?

What's the logic behind the meaning? `no hace falta (si no haces nada)/(si no pasa nada)`? == **nothing wrong happens** (if you refrain from doing that).

Comment: I've replied to the main question, but I'm not sure I understand the second part. There's nothing in *no hacer falta* about wrong things happening or about refraining from doing things. If you could clarify that, I can edit my answer to include that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***No hace falta*** is just a form of the phrase *hacer falta* "to be necessary". The logic behind it is that *falta* means "lack". When something is needed, you can say that something makes or causes a lack, or something is an instance of lack. If you say

> *no hace falta*

then that literally means (something) does not make or cause a lack; it's not lacking, and therefore not needed.

There's no tone of judgement in this phrase; *no hace falta* can be used to tell someone off, or to spare them unneeded work.

Comment: I thought falta meant something related to false

Comment: @nylypej Actually it does, etymologically, but it's not obvious. You'd need to go back to Latin and before... It also has a relationship with *fallar* "to fail".

Comment: Etymologic doesn't have to be logic. Think `wanted`. Something wanted may be desired or missing.

Comment: @enxaneta what you've shown here is called "logic"

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Pablo's excellent answer, the noun falta 'lack' (which by the way also means 'shortage; mistake; fault, defect') is derived from the verb faltar 'to be missing/absent', 'to be lacking, to be needed', 'to lack, not have enough', and 'to insult, be rude, foul' (in sports)